# Removing App Profile Pages - missing migration option

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-apps

Facebook announced that they are about to [remove app profile pages](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/) and allowing to migrate existing likes to a "regular" facebook page.

From some reason, i do not have the migration option on the top of my app profile page as it supposed to be according to their post.

I made sure to open a page with the same app name and set its category to Brands & Products / App.

What am i missing? Is there a way to activate the migration from another place (rather than this banner)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think not all App will get it immediately.  I just have it today and have migrated my app profile page to a new page a created under Brands & Products / App.

Unfortunately, once I migrated, I don't have accessed to the old page and lost all my precious wall content... It had been a very active interaction channel between us and our fans....

Is there any channel we can feedback and vote to migrate our wall content as well?

Comment: only likes are migrated http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

Comment: i just got the option today. I guess they are rolling it out gradually.